# Ruby/ActiveRecord not detecting changes after stripping whitespace from field

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to remove whitespace and carriage returns from various fields in a MySQL database using the mysql2 adapter and ActiveRecord: 
Ruby 1.9.3p194 
ActiveRecord 3.2.8 
MySQL 5.5.28

```
foo = People.find(1)
foo.name => "\rJohn Jones"
foo.name.lstrip! => "John Jones"
foo.name => "John Jones"
foo.changes => {} #no changes detected to foo.name???
foo.save => true # but does nothing to database.
```

if I do:

```
foo.name = "John Jones"
foo.save => true
People.find(1).name => "John Jones" # this works and saves to database
```

I've searched all over for this... any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do in-place modifications on model attributes, no assignment occurs and the model is unaware any changes have been made. The correct way to do this is to reassign:

```
foo.name = foo.name.lstrip
```

This triggers the `name=` method and the dirty tracking is engaged.

Comment: Good to hear. You can use the check-mark to highlight working answers and accept it as the solution.